# clear input box on certain condition react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a `get` request to a quiz api. When the user gets the answer correct the next answer is shown.

This is all working well, however I have got into some trouble when trying to clear the input box when the user gets the answer correct. [I read this earlier](https://github.com/ruanyf/react-demos#demo09-form)  and as far as I can tell it should be following the same logic.

Can anyone spot what is wrong here?

```
var Quiz = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
                question: '',
                answer: '',
                value: '',
                score: 0
            }
    },

    getData: function() { 
        $.get('http://jservice.io/api/random', function(data){
            var response = data[0];
            console.log(response)

            this.setState({
                question: response.question,
                answer: response.answer
            })
        }.bind(this));
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.serverRequest = this.getData()
    },

    checkAnswer: function(event) {
        if(event.target.value.toLowerCase() === this.state.answer.toLowerCase()) {
            this.setState({
                score: this.state.score + 1,
                value: ''
            })
            this.getData();
        }
    },

    skipQuestion: function() {
        this.getData();
    },

    render: function() {
        var value = this.state.value
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.question}</p>
                <input type='text' value={value}  onChange={this.checkAnswer}/>
                <p onClick={this.skipQuestion}>New question</p>
                <p>{this.state.score}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

});
```

Comment: Is your text input working at all? like accepting input and displaying? When I copied I had to change the code to get that working and it also clears just want to make sure you had the same issue before answering with what i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved this code into a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/coxepeziqu/edit?html,js,console,output) and your input clearing logic is working fine. However, as @finalfreq mentioned in your implementation it's impossible to type a full answer in to the input box, each input gets recognized but is never displayed. The fix for that is shown below. The only change is adding the `else` case in `checkAnswer`:

```
var Quiz = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
            question: '',
            answer: '',
            value: '',
            score: 0
        }
},

getData: function() { 
    $.get('http://jservice.io/api/random', function(data){
        var response = data[0];
        console.log(response)

        this.setState({
            question: response.question,
            answer: response.answer
        })
    }.bind(this));
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = this.getData()
},

checkAnswer: function(event) {
    if(event.target.value.toLowerCase() === this.state.answer.toLowerCase()) {
        this.setState({
            score: this.state.score + 1,
            value: ''
        })
        this.getData();
    } else {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value.toLowerCase()
        })
    }
},

skipQuestion: function() {
    this.getData();
},

render: function() {
    var value = this.state.value
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{this.state.question}</p>
            <input type='text' value={value}  onChange={this.checkAnswer}/>
            <p onClick={this.skipQuestion}>New question</p>
            <p>{this.state.score}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

});
```

Comment: is this the cleanest/best way to fix this?

Comment: If you're using controlled components, which in this case you probably should, then yes this is the accepted way to do this. Facebook's [article on controlled vs uncontrolled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) will help explain this better.